# How can generate random name with numbers

Tags: ruby, cucumber

events_data.yml

```
event_create_form:
  event_name: 'Event Created by Webdriver #{rand(1...100)'
```

I want to generate random names with digits , here i have added rand method digits , but not generating it

how can i generate randmon name in .yml file for test data 
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in YAML, as it represents a static format without support of generating contents on-the-fly.

You may however write a placeholder which will be interpolated from **ruby** code afterwards.
Like

```
 event_create_form:
  event_name: 'Event Created by Webdriver %{random_number}'
```

Then in a ruby code which uses the .yml file like in a view do the interpolation:

```
require 'yaml'

my_yml = YAML.load_file 'events_data.yml'
my_yml['event_create_form']['event_name'] % {random_number: rand(1..100)}
# "Event Created by Webdriver 69"
```